# Rally: How to move de-scoped stories from an iteration/release to backlog

Tags: agile, rally, backlog

I have some stories which were planned for a sprint but due to sudden changes/prioritization they have been de-scoped now for current release and maybe taken up in some latter release. Since we dont have any visibility for those stories for now, we would like to move them to backlog and give low priority. 
- Is there a way in rally to do that or i have to create new stories for those under backlog and delete the current ones?
- Can i create a rule ( like notification rule) which creates a report of the stories in backlog and email it to a DL every month.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create new stories and delete old ones if all you need is to unschedule them from a release.

Create a custom view on User Stories summary page (Plan>User Stories) with a condition

```
Release = SomeReleaseName
```

In this example `r3`.

[image]

In the Actions menu in the upper right select Multi-Edit and change Release value to Unscheduled:

[image]

There is no functionality out of box that would create a report of backlog items and email it like notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you mean there is no way right now to move the story to backlog ? We can un-schedule it and also assign it to some release but we would like to have it under backlog and rank it

Comment: For a story to be in backlog it has to be unscheduled from Release and Iteration. There is not "drag and drop in backlog" action. User story must be a leaf story and must be unscheduled to appear in a backlog.